# Use only Emacs default keybindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

(update: a valid answer can include "there is no neat/automated way of doing this) I've been keeping myself busy with other things but if I know there is no neat way of doing what is requested below then I'll just get started on finding some manual way as much as possible.

I have been looking online for a way to ensure all my emac buffers use the same keybindings. However I use exwm & certain applications such as libreoffice have their own keybindings which take precedence over emacs keybindings. Is there some code I can use to make all emacs default keybindings take precedence over any other application?

A specific example is this situation:

I want to be able to use the default bindings to change which buffer I am using position wise. I do this using (windmove-default-keybindings) however when I switch to an application like libreoffice writer, that application makes it so S-arrowkey doesn't move my active buffer anymore (libreoffice takes over that keybinding). I wish for windmove to still control what S-arrow key does.

In general this means I want emacs to be the only application in control of any keybinding. Is the only way to do this is to set each keybinding as global manually? and will a global keybinding take precedence over applications like libreoffice?

Comment: Have you checked the EXWM documentation?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Virtually every key on your keyboard will have a default Emacs binding, including letters, numbers, and punctuation.  You wouldn't be able to type *anything* in libreoffice (or whatever program) if EXWM did not pass any of Emacs' default keybindings through to other applications.  Think carefully about what your *real* requirement is, and update the question accordingly.